# Windows 7: security problem does not let me execute certain files

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am trying to download Photoshop CS5 from the Adobe site. This downloads a file called AdobeDownloadAssistant.exe. When attempting to execute this file, however, Windows 7 tells me that this software cannot be executed. My Windows is not in English so I don't know what the exact message in the English version would be, but translated directly it looks something like this:

```
Software from this editor cannot be executed on the system. Unblock this editor to execute this software.
```

I have UAC disabled, so I am not really sure where this is. The Windows help is not helping either.

Thanks!

Comment: If you right-click on the file and select properties - Is there an option to unblock? It's part of the UAC stuff I think just because it could 'potentially' be malicious.

Comment: @steve the OP has UAC disabled.

Comment: The Unblock "feature" is far more irritating with zip files if you forget to Unblock before you unzip the file.  Then you have to manually unblock each file individually.  It's a pain in the rear.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://darrenmyher.wordpress.com/2007/03/22/how-to-permanently-unblock-files-that-came-from-the-internet-sysinternals-streams-utility-zones-vista-and-blocked-files-in-ie/) will help.